# Flutter audioplayers 1.1.1 version, no sound at all on android imulator but works only on web browser

Tags: android, flutter, dart, audio, audio-player

I have used a last version  of audio player 1.1.1
and i faced this problem that i cann’t play sound at all on android imulator but i works well only on web browser I’ve put this line in manifest

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

and this is my code that I’m useing to play sound :

```
 final player = AudioPlayer();
                  player.play(DeviceFileSource("assets/assets_music-2.mp3"));
```

i used an player.play(AssetSource("assets/assets_music-2.mp3")); Method but it did’t help me

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, can the audio on real device, but no sound from android emulator